# WebStorm put spaces instead of tabs

Tags: webstorm

I have setup WebStorm to use tabs under Preferences -> Editor -> Code Style -> Javascript. I have checked "Use tab character". I have not checked "Smart tabs".

When I make a tab character in any javascript editor I get two spaces.

Why does this happen?

I have a different project on the same computer on which this problem is not present.

I'm running on Mac Book Pro and WebStorm 2017.2.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have `.editorconfig` file(s) in your project? Please try disabling EditorConfig support in `Settings | Editor | Code Style` by unchecking **Enable Editorconfig support** checkbox - does it help? Settings in the project `.editorconfig` override WebStorm preferences

Comment: Wow! Thanks, it was exactly what I needed.